# Converting MSVS 2010 project to MSVS 2012 RC but get error "The C++ standard doesn't provide a hash for this type"

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have a project working fine under MSVS 2010 SP1.
I'm trying to convert it to MSVS 2012 RC. I had to change some stuff, mainly related to C++ header/lib paths and MFC custom stuff. But I have one last hurdle to clear.

In MSVC 2010, I'm using a lot of `unordered_map<basic_string<TCHAR>, int>` or `map<basic_string<TCHAR>, int>`. It compiles fine. But in MSVS 2012, I just get this error:
"The C++ standard doesn't provide a hash for this type"

After searching a bit on the net, I found out that MSVS 2012 should be more close to the C++11 standard, and that the standard only defines hash functions for basic types and 4 defined string types (among them `string` and `wstring`, but `basic_string` not included).
So I changed all `basic_string<TCHAR>` to `wstring` but to no avail... I still get the same error.

What should I do to be able to compile my app again?

Comment: Probably in VS2010 you had multibyte disabled so `TCHAR` mapped to `char` and now you have multibyte chars enabled so `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`. Try changing these settings in project properties.

Comment: `basic_string<TCHAR>` is either `std::string` or `std::wstring` (both just typedefs), depending on your project settings. The only difference in C++11 is that string `hash<>` is now in `<string>` and not `<functional>`.

Comment: Thanks Bo, I had to include <string> everywhere, while before I didn't need to do it. I have to wait 6 hours before I can put an answer...In the meantime, feel free to do it yourself :)

Comment: @OOEngineer: That was a bug already, regardless of `hash<>`. You needed `<string>` for `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`.

Comment: MSalters: well, I guess you can tell VC++ team that there still is a big bug in their std lib implementation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently OOEngineer used `basic_string` without including the `<string>` header. Part of the functionality might be visible anyway, through indirect includes by other headers.

When VS2010 was released, the then proposed standard put all `std::hash<>` specializations in the `<functional>` header. In the final C++11 standard it was decided that it was better to put these together with the respective container, so some `hash<>` specializations were moved to `<string>`, `<vector>`, etc.

So, to used all (or *any*, really) functionality of `std::string`, you have to include the `<string>` header yourself and not rely on another system header doing so.