# C++ Hash function for string in unordered_map

Tags: c++, string, c++11, key, unordered-map

It seems as if C++ does not have a hash function for strings in the standard library. Is this true?

What is a working example of using a string as a key in an unordered_map that will work with any c++ compiler?

Comment: I'm curious what gave you the idea that the standard library (at least a library that supported `unordered_map`) didn't support a hash function for `std::string`?

Comment: "error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type." when I try to use string.

Comment: Perhaps this SO answer might be related to what's happening to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11157019/12711  Are you using `basic_string<>` directly instead of through the `std:string` typedef?  You might be able to use `basic_string<>` for some purposes without a compiler error because another header happens to be pulling in `xstring` (which gives you `basic_string<>`, but not `std::hash<string>`)

Comment: So the bottom line is - make sure you have a `#include <string>` if you're trying to use strings in an `unordered_map<>` - actually,  any time you're using `std::string`.  Unfortunately, the compiler will sometimes let you get away without the include because of side effects from other includes.  then when you add a use that actually requires the `string` header you get a mysterious, non-obvious error from the compiler.

Comment: What happens to me sometimes is the IDE incorrectly change my `#include <unordered_map>` to `#include <bits/unordered_map.h>`. So make sure you have included the correct lib.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

C++ STL provides template [specializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash) of `std::hash` for the various string classes. You could just specify `std::string` as key type for `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
    map["string"] = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the implicit behavior from the type constructor, is it not? Specifying `std::hash<std::string>>` when you already have an `std::unordered_map<std::string>` is just redundant.

Comment: I think this should be compiled with option "-std=c++0x"?

Comment: @Bloodmoon, Yes (I'd say, with `-std=c++11`), `unordered_map` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: JohnLeidegren is right, but for learners, the explicit code might be helpful: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int, std::hash<std::string>> map;` (the original answer before editing). Here, `std::hash<std::string>` can be omitted because [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is defined as `template<class Key, class T, class Hash=std::hash<Key>, ...> class unordered_map;`.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into this today (actually with `wstring`, not `string`, but it's the same deal):  using `wstring` as a key in an `unordered_map` generates an error about no hash function being available for that type.

The solution for me was to add:

```
#include <string>
```

Believe it or not, without the `#include` directive I still had the `wstring` type available but apparently NOT the ancillary functions like the hash.  Simply adding the include above fixed it.

Comment: This answer most directly addressed my issue (not including `<string>`)

Answer (score 17):

Actually, there is `std::hash<std::string>`

But there it is how you can use another hash function:

```
struct StringHasher {
    size_t operator()(const std::string& t) const {
          //calculate hash here.
    }
}

unordered_map<std::string, ValueType, StringHasher>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a `CustomType` and you want to plug into the STL infrastructure this is what you could do.

```
namespace std
{
//namespace tr1
//{
    // Specializations for unordered containers

    template <>
    struct hash<CustomType> : public unary_function<CustomType, size_t>
    {
        size_t operator()(const CustomType& value) const
        {
            return 0;
        }
    };

//} // namespace tr1

template <>
struct equal_to<CustomType> : public unary_function<CustomType, bool>
{
    bool operator()(const CustomType& x, const CustomType& y) const
    {
        return false;
    }
};

} // namespace std
```

If you then want to create say a `std::unordered_map<CustomType>` the STL will find the `hash` and `equal_to` functions without you having to do anything more with the template. This is how I like to write my custom equality comparer that support unordered data structures.

Comment: Note:  unary_function is deprecated.  Better to provide the typedefs result_type and argument_type yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was really distraction.

I had a type X for which I implemented hashing for **const& X** an utilized it somewhere with

```
std::unordered_map<const X, int> m_map;
```

Then I wanted to have another map which key are of the type `X` and did:

```
std::unordered_map<X, int> map_x;
```

Notice the **LACK** of `const` on the second case.